# Using the Residue theorem to solve contour integral $\oint_{|z|=R}\frac{z^2}{1-e^{2\pi i z^3}}dz$ with $n<R^3<n+1$ for positive integer $n$.

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, contour-integration, residue-calculus

I'm a second-year undergraduate in a non-major complex analysis course. We just started looking at using residues to compute the values of contour integrals, and I've run into a homework problem that's giving me some trouble. I spent a lot of time on this one and I think I got it, but my answer is off by a negative compared to the one in a student-created answer bank that on rare occasion does have incorrect answers, but is usually right. I'm looking for help confirming my thought process and making sure that I didn't make any mistakes here.

The integral is $\oint_{|z|=R}\frac{z^2}{1-e^{2\pi i z^3}}dz$ with $n<R^3<n+1$ for positive integer $n$. I started by identifying all singularities as those $z$ where $1-e^{2\pi i z^3}=0$, and discovered that this is true exactly when $z^3=k$ for some integer $k$. I then let $z=re^{i\theta}$, which gives $z^3=k\Rightarrow r^3e^{3i\theta}=ke^{i(0)}\Rightarrow r=k^{1/3},\theta=\frac{2\pi l}{3}$, where $l$ is an integer. Since $z$ is like a "3rd root of $k$" (like a 3rd root of unity), there are 3 of them with unique positions in the complex plane, these are those $z$ with $l=0,1,2$, or $\theta=0,\frac{2\pi}{3},\frac{4\pi}{3}$, and all with $r=k^{1/3}$. Then, for a particular integer $k$, we have 3 distinct roots that solve $1-e^{1\pi i z^3}=0$.

However, the integers $k$ that we are concerned with are restricted by those that fall within the interior of the contour $|z|=R$. These are those $k$ where $|k|\leq n$, or $k=0,\pm 1,\pm 2,\dots , \pm n$. This is because of the fact that if a number $z$ is to fall within the interior of $|z|=R$, then its modulus $|z|$ should surely be less than $R$, or $|z|<R$, which implies that $|z|^3<R^3$, and since we have $n<R^3<n+1$, this implies that $|z|^3\leq n<R^3<n+1$ (All of this was difficult for me to visualize at first. I can't really think of a better way to explain this fact, and to be honest, I only feel like I've half convinced myself of it).

Given that we have our general singularity $z=re^{i\theta}$ from above, and the constraint that $|z|^3\leq n$ for a point to be in the contour, we can now put a restriction on the values of $k$ that allow $z=re^{i\theta}=k^{1/3}e^{i\theta}$ to fall within the interior of the contour. We have $|z|=|k^{1/3}|\Rightarrow |z|^3=|k|\leq n$, so we select $k=0,\pm 1,\pm 2,\dots , \pm n$ as previously stated.

Now that we have a finite number of singularities that fall within the interior of the contour, we can count them and see that there are $2n$ values of $k$ (not counting $k=0$) and 3 values of $l$, which makes for $6n$ distinct singularities. When $k=0$, we only count 1 singularity, since the length of $z$ just becomes 0 and changing to different angles makes no difference in its distinct position on the complex plane. We let all of the $6n$ distinct non-zero singularities be defined as $z_{k,l}=k^{1/3}e^{i\frac{2\pi}{3}l}$ for ranges of $k$ and $l$ previously defined.

We now compute the integral using the Residue theorem. Let $f(z)=\frac{z^2}{1-e^{2\pi i z^3}}$. This is
$\oint_{|z|=R}\frac{z^2}{1-e^{2\pi i z^3}}dz
=\oint_{|z|=R}f(z)dz=2\pi i \left[
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{l=0}^{2}(Res(f(z),z_{k,l}))
+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{l=0}^{2}(Res(f(z),z_{-k,l}))
+Res(f(z),0)\right]$.

Now to compute the residue for each non-zero singularity $z_{k,l}$. I claim that each $z_{k,l}$ is a finite pole of order 1, or a simple pole. This can be shown by taking
\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{z\to z_{k,l}}(z-z_{k,l})f(z)\\
=\lim_{z\to z_{k,l}}(z-z_{k,l})\frac{z^2}{1-e^{2\pi i z^3}}\\
=\lim_{z\to z_{k,l}}\frac{z^3-z_{k,l}z^2}{1-e^{2\pi i z^3}}\\
=\lim_{z\to z_{k,l}}\frac{3z^2-2z_{k,l}z}{-e^{2\pi i z^3}(6\pi i z^2)}\\
=-\frac{1}{6\pi i}\lim_{z\to z_{k,l}}\frac{3-2z_{k,l}z^{-1}}{e^{2\pi i z^3}}\\
=-\frac{1}{6\pi i}\frac{3-2z_{k,l}z_{k,l}^{-1}}{e^{2\pi i z_{k,l}^3}}\\
=-\frac{1}{6\pi i}\frac{1}{e^{2\pi i z_{k,l}^3}}
\end{eqnarray}

Since this value is certainly not zero, each non-zero $z_{k,l}$ is indeed a simple pole, and it just happens that the limit we just computed is the same limit that computes exactly the residue at the point $z_{k,l}$, since it is a simple pole. Since $z_{k,l}^3=k$ as we have previously defined we then have $-\frac{1}{6\pi i}\frac{1}{e^{2\pi i k}}$, where $e^{2\pi i k}=1$ since the coefficient $k$ is an integer. This leaves us with a residue of $-\frac{1}{6\pi i}$ for all non-zero $z_{k,l}$.

Now we look at the residue at $z=0$. We similarly use a limit to simultaneously show that $f(z)$ has a simple pole at $z=0$ and compute the residue at that pole.

\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{z\to 0}zf(z)\\
=\lim_{z\to 0}z\frac{z^2}{1-e^{2\pi i z^3}}\\
=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{z^3}{1-e^{2\pi i z^3}}\\
=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{3z^2}{-e^{2\pi i z^3}(6\pi i z^2)}\\
=-\frac{1}{2\pi i}\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{1}{e^{2\pi i z^3}}\\
=-\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\end{eqnarray}

This gives the residue $Res(f(z),0)=-\frac{1}{2\pi i}$. With the residues $Res(f(z),z_{k,l})=-\frac{1}{6\pi i}$ for all valid $k,l$ from before, this gives

$$
\oint_{|z|=R}\frac{z^2}{1-e^{2\pi i z^3}}dz
=\oint_{|z|=R}f(z)dz
=2\pi i \left[
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{l=0}^{2}(Res(f(z),z_{k,l}))
+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{l=0}^{2}(Res(f(z),z_{-k,l}))
+Res(f(z),0)\right]
=
2\pi i \left[
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{l=0}^{2}(-\frac{1}{6\pi i})
+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{l=0}^{2}(-\frac{1}{6\pi i})
-\frac{1}{2\pi i}\right]
=
2\pi i \left[
3n(-\frac{1}{6\pi i})
+3n(-\frac{1}{6\pi i})
-\frac{1}{2\pi i}\right]
=
2\pi i \left[
6n(-\frac{1}{6\pi i})
-\frac{1}{2\pi i}\right]
=
6n(-\frac{1}{3})
-1
=
-2n-1
$$

So my end answer is $-2n-1$, but the answer bank says $2n+1$, without much additional explanation. Is there any place I messed up? Thanks.

Comment: Upvote for clear explanation. I guess this for sure is one of those occasion where your Student Created Answer Bank got it wrong.Good Work